# Dynamic Array Memory Allocation with void**

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I am trying to implement a dynamic array which must have the following struct:

```
typedef struct DArray{
    void **array;
    int capacity;
    int size;
    void (*display)(FILE *, void *); //function pointer to a non-generic display function
} DArray;
```

However, with the current behavior, the array doesn't seem to resize, and throws a segfault any time I try to access an index that's not zero.  The constructor and insert function is as follows:

```
DArray *newDArray(void (*d)(FILE *,void *)){
    DArray *myDarray = malloc(sizeof(DArray));
    myDarray->array = malloc(sizeof(void *)); //size = 1 for now, otherwise multiply by array length
    myDarray->capacity = 1;
    myDarray->size = 0;
    myDarray->display = d;
    return myDarray;
}

void insertDArray(DArray *a,void *v){
    if (a->size < a->capacity)
        a->array[a->size] = v;
    else{
        void **newArray = malloc(sizeof(void *) * a->capacity * 2); //double size
        for (int i = 0; i <= a->size; i++)
            newArray[i] = a->array[i];  //clone old array
        a->capacity = a->capacity * 2;
        free(a->array);
        a->array = newArray;
    }
    a->size++;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding my pointers here.  I think what's happening is the pointer to a->array still points to the old, unresized array, but doing `*a->array = newArray;` does not work either.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Any reason for a single start (`void*`) not to suffice?

Comment: @StoryTeller the array must be implemented to handle generic (void*) types.  I believe I should have an array of pointers, hence the double star.

Comment: If you insert pointers into the array, you don't need a `size` member. If you insert objects, you don't need an array of pointers

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why a separate `malloc` followed by a copy-loop? Why not use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)? Maybe not so unrelated after all, since using `realloc` would incidentally fix your problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller Could you explain why I would not need a size member?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude unfortunately, the only memory allocation function allowed in this implementation is `malloc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a buffer overrun caused by this loop. Should be `i < a->size` since if capacity is 5, you only expand it when size is also 5 and thus you'll be accessing the 6th element in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a->size; i++)
```

You're also not added the new value when you resize. Possibly change the logic of your code along the lines of...

```
if (a->size == a->capacity)
{
   /* resize array */
}
a->array[a->size++] = v;
```

...taking care to check the results of using `malloc` or `realloc` etc...

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  However, I still am getting a segfault when I try to access a->array[1] after inserting two elements.  Is there anything in my insert code that could have caused this?

Comment: @ScottSinischo Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Like how you use these functions?

Comment: It'd help if you included which line your debugger is saying the segfault is happening, but I noticed another problem with the code as-is and updated my answer.